# No ObservableObject of type CarouselViewModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for CarouselViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view

Tags: swift, firebase, struct, card

I am trying to make a card and print a DataBase inside but I get an error "Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type CarouselViewModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for CarouselViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view." here is the code:

Start of struct with error :

```
struct Home: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: CarouselViewModel
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = NewsViewModel()
    @State private var isModalOpen: Bool = false
    @Namespace var animation
    var body: some View {
```

code with error :

````
ZStack{
                    ForEach(model.cards.indices.reversed(),id: \.self){index in
                        HStack {
                            CardView(card: model.cards[index], animation: animation)
                                .frame(width: getCardWidth(index: index), height: getCardHeight(index: index))
                                .offset(x: getCardOffset(index: index))
                                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: getCardRotation(index: index)))
                            Spacer(minLength: 0)
                        }
                        .frame(height: 400)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .offset(x: model.cards[index].offset)
                        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                    .onChanged({ (value) in
                                        onChanged(value: value, index: index)
                                    }).onEnded({ (value) in
                                        onEnd(value: value, index: index)
                                    }))
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top,25)
                .padding(.horizontal,30)
```
Thanks for help
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you instantiate the `Home` view, you have to add an `.environmentObject` modifier that passes an instance of `CarouselViewModel` to it.

I don't know what your exact code looks like (or what `CarouselViewModel` takes as parameters), but it'll look something like:

```
//somewhere in the parent view:
@StateObject private var model = CarouselViewModel() //if iOS 13, use @ObservedObject

//where you instantiate `Home`:
Home().environmentObject(model)
```

Note that this will *also* be an error if you try to use `Home` in a SwiftUI Preview and it doesn't have this `.environmentObject` code.