# SwiftUI if network not connected

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

So I have a view that if for what ever reason the user can't get access to our server, be it for:

- network issues
- server outages

I need it to show this view. At the moment I have away to do this via an error if it is not able to access our servers, however I want to know if their is a connected or not connected network before it even goes to try our website.

The idea is a popup screen that shows until the user either connects to a wifi or a cell reception.

However I have tried this code:

```
import Network
import SwiftUI

// An enum to handle the network status
enum NetworkStatus: String {
    case connected
    case disconnected
}

class Monitor: ObservableObject {
    private let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")

    @Published var status: NetworkStatus = .connected
  
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            // Monitor runs on a background thread so we need to publish
            // on the main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if path.status == .satisfied {
                    print("We're connected!")
                    self.status = .connected
                  

                } else {
                    print("No connection.")
                    self.status = .disconnected
                }
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
}
```

and then I have added the following to my SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: SwiftUI.View {
    @EnvironmentObject var monitor: Monitor
    
    init() {
      
    }

 var body: some SwiftUI.View {
HStack{
Text("HELLO WORLD")
}.onAppear{
print(monitor.status)
}
}
```

However it crashes the app, with the following error

```
SwiftUI:0: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Monitor found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Monitor may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

Comment: The error message is quite explicit, have  you set the environment object? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views

Comment: But I did up the top @EnvironmentObjec.

Comment: That is just a declaration of the variable pointing to the environment object. See the linked article

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No ObservableObject of type CarouselViewModel found. A View.environmentObject(\_:) for CarouselViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66834291/no-observableobject-of-type-carouselviewmodel-found-a-view-environmentobject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring an `@EnvironmentObject` in your SwiftUI view gets you a reference to an existing environment object but first, you have to create it and add it to the environment.

For code that could be accessed anywhere in your application, perhaps the best place for it is at the app layer. Assuming you're using the SwiftUI app lifecycle, it could look something like this:

```swift
struct MyApp: App {
  @StateObject private var monitor = Monitor()

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
        .environmentObject(monitor)
    }
  }
}
```

As long as your views are children of `ContentView()`, they'll then be able to access your `Monitor` instance via the `@EnvironmentObject` declaration.