# Saving UserInfo received via WatchConnectivity to CoreData

Tags: swiftui, watchos, watchconnectivity

Hi I was wonder if anyone can help. I have watch app that does a check then passes two bit data to main app (a String and a Int). Then I want it to save them to CoreData. I have tried a few things. The Comment out code is want I need to save them to CoreData.

```
#if os(iOS)
// With This get *SwiftUI:0: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type DataController found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for DataController may be missing as an ancestor of this view.*
@EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController

// This does saved to CoreData but then crashes the iOS app!
//    @ObservedObject var dataController = DataController()

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

    print("Data received \(userInfo)")
//            let viewContext = dataController.container.viewContext

    if let isDefect = userInfo["isDefect"] as? Bool {
        if isDefect {
// This is another data that save to different entity
            print("Defect")
//                let defect = Defect(context: viewContext)
        } else {
            print("Vehicle check")
//                let checkData = CheckData(context: viewContext)
//
            if let bonnet = userInfo["bonnet"] as? String {
//                    checkData.bonnet = bonnet
                print(bonnet)
            }
//
            if let numberDefect = userInfo["numberDefect"] as? Int {
//                    checkData.numberDefect = Int64(numberDefect)
                print("\(numberDefect)")
            }
//
//                checkData.dateCreated = Date()
        }
    }

//            dataController.save()
    }
}

// other Protocol methods that are required
#else
// watch Protocol method
#endif
```

Comment: The error you have with `EnvironmentObject` is because you haven't supplied an object via `.environmentObject()` on a parent view. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66835156/560942 for example.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. It was not how to use the `EnvironmentObject` as I have used this in a number of places in the main app (`.environmentObject()` is on the `@main` `App`. It is how to take the `userInfo: [String : Any]` and get that data to CoreData of the App.

Comment: Observing SwiftUI wrappers is only for SwiftUI Views. You are obviously in a class (WCSessionDelegate requires class/NSObject) so your code likely fails because you are using SwiftUI wrappers in a class. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. Just conjecture

Comment: @Nigel that’s why I didn’t leave it as an answer, because it doesn’t seem to be the main issue. But, your first comment in your code makes it very clear that this is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you make all this available to your iOS and WatchKit Extension you will have a working sample

```
import SwiftUI

struct WatchConnectView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CheckData.dateCreated, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default) private var items: FetchedResults<CheckData>
    let wcManager = WatchConnectivityManager.shared
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("send vehicle check", action: {
                wcManager.sendVehicleCheck()
            })
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text("CheckData at \(item)")
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct WatchConnectView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WatchConnectView()
    }
}
//This would handle all the work for watch connectivity regardless of target
import WatchConnectivity
class WatchConnectivityManager: NSObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    private let session: WCSession = .default
    var isReachable: Bool{
        session.isReachable
    }
    //Need singleton because of delegate
    static let shared: WatchConnectivityManager = WatchConnectivityManager()
    //If you have target specific code it is easier to manage if it is separated
    let targetSpecifc = WatchConnectivityManagerTS()
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
    func sendUserInfo(userInfo: [String: Any]){
        if isReachable{
            session.transferUserInfo(userInfo)
        }
    }
    func sendVehicleCheck(bonnet: String = "Some Bonnet", numberDefect: Int = Int.random(in: 0...50)){
        var userInfo: [String: Any] = [:]
        userInfo["isDefect"] = false
        userInfo["bonnet"] = bonnet
        userInfo["numberDefect"] = numberDefect
        
        sendUserInfo(userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}
extension WatchConnectivityManager: WCSessionDelegate{
#if os(iOS)
    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
        
    }
    
    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
        
    }
#endif
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error{
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) {
        if let isDefect = userInfo["isDefect"] as? Bool {
            if isDefect {
                print("Defect")
            } else {
                print("Vehicle check")
                targetSpecifc.saveVehicleCheck(userInfo: userInfo)
                
            }
        }
    }
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {

    }
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {

    }
}
//Asuming CoreData is only on iOS
#if !os(watchOS)
class DataController{
    //Access to the context depends on how you are creating the stack.
    //This is with the standard PersistenceController setup that
    //comes with XCode sample code
    let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
    init(){}
    func newCheckData() -> CheckData{
        let new  = CheckData(context: context)
        new.dateCreated = Date()
        return new
    }
    
    func saveContext(){
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
}
class WatchConnectivityManagerTS{
    let dataController = DataController()
    func saveVehicleCheck(userInfo: [String: Any]){
        let checkData = self.dataController.newCheckData()
        
        if let bonnet = userInfo["bonnet"] as? String {
            checkData.bonnet = bonnet
            print(bonnet)
        }
        
        if let numberDefect = userInfo["numberDefect"] as? Int {
            checkData.numberDefect = Int64(numberDefect)
            print("\(numberDefect)")
        }
        dataController.saveContext()
    }
}
#else
class WatchConnectivityManagerTS{
    //In case there is a reason for the watch to receive vechicle checks
    func saveVehicleCheck(userInfo: [String: Any]){
        print("save attempt on watch \(userInfo)")
    }
}
#endif
```