# cannot find uiviewcontrollerrepresentable in scope

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, watch, watchconnectivity

I have a WatchKit extension to my app and I need to modify the data in the content view with updates from the app on the phone.  So I am using the code below... but the compiler errors out saying it can find UViewControllerRepresentable in scope

```
struct ContentView: View, UViewControllerRepresentable
  {
  
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack
      {
          ...
      }
  }
```

Comment: \Hi Scott, did you check both targets in the target membership? It's in the inspector view.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewControllerRepresentable` is not available for watch.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

There is no need because WatchKit/WatchOS doesn't have `UIViewController`s
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller

SwiftUI `View`s are available but you can't use `UIKit`'s `UIView`s/`UIViewController`s

Whenever you have to redesign a `View` for a watchOS compatible version you can name it the same as the `iOS` target's version and give it the same `init`.

If you keep the target memberships selected appropriately the compiler will chose the current target's version.

Comment: Thank you very much.  How do I update the view with data from an application update from watch connectivity?

Comment: @ScottTarone that is a different question you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68071301/saving-userinfo-received-via-watchconnectivity-to-coredata/68085918#68085918) for some help with that. If I answered your question can you accept the answer above? It is the green check mark.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll have a look